# Interrupt метод: что он делает и зачем он нужен

Tags: java, многопоточность

Добрый день. Читаю про многопоточность и столкнулся с непонятным методом interrupt ? Объясните пожалуйста, что он делает и зачем он нужен ? Я так понял, что его задача состоит в том, что бы "будить" потоки, у которыз были вызваны методы wait, sleep.

Answer (score 3):

Как говорится в документации: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html

При вызове прерывания треда сигнализирует, что тред должен прервать выполнение текущей задачи и выполнить что-то другое. Что другое он будет делать, зависит то того, что реализовал программист, но в большинстве случаев тред просто прерывает свою работу.

В статье есть примеры, как чаще всего использовать interrupt.

Comment: то есть, этот метод нужен для остановки потока ?

Comment: Чаще всего да, но не обязательно.